# algorithm efficiency:finding the 5 largest elements in an array

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

```
typedef std::map<uint16_t, uint32_t> TSrcMap;
TPSrcMap sp;
TSrcMap::iterator its;
/*Code to populate the array_start.*/

/*Code to populate the array_end.*/

typedef struct port_count
{
        uint32_t port_number;
        uint32_t port_count;
}port_count_t;

port_count_t pcount[5];
memset(pcount,0,sizeof(pcount));
size_t structs_len = sizeof(pcount)/sizeof(port_count_t);
for(its = stcp.begin(); its != stcp.end();its++)
{
      if(pcount[smallest_index].port_count < (*its).second)
      {
            pcount[smallest_index].port_count = (*its).second;
            pcount[smallest_index].port_number = (*its).first;
#ifdef USEQSORT
            qsort(pcount, structs_len, sizeof(port_count_t), struct_cmp_by_port_count);
#else
            std::sort(pcount,(pcount+structs_len),cmp_by_port_count);
#endif
      }
}


#ifdef USEQSORT
/* qsort struct comparision function compare port frequency*/
int struct_cmp_by_port_count(const void *a, const void *b)
{
        port_count_t *ia = (port_count_t *)a;
        port_count_t *ib = (port_count_t *)b;
        return (ia->port_count - ib->port_count);
}
#else
/* qsort struct comparision function compare port frequency*/
int cmp_by_port_count(const port_count_t& a, const port_count_t& b)
{
        return (a.port_count < b.port_count);
}
#endif
```

I have a large std::map structure which maps port_count to port_number.I have to find the largest 5 elements based on port_count.(where key is the port_number).I have a single parse loop given above,which calls a sorting algorithm (qsort or std::sort) on the array of size 5.Is this the most efficient way to achieve this?In terms of number of calls to the sorting function.Is there a better way to do this,in terms of computational efficiency?Also I tried both qsort and std::sort and both of them seem to perform about the same.Is this because the size of the array that I am sorting is too small to produce a significant impact.I am trying to understand this algorithm in terms of it complexity.Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't have to do a full sort every time you add an element to the top 5. Since the 5 in the array are already sorted all you have to do is find where to insert the new element and move all the necessary elements down 1 (discarding the last element of course). You should be able to do this in `O(n)` which is faster than any sort method. However, since the array is only 5 elements any gain from this would probably be negligible.

Comment: why is my question given a -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into one of my favorite often-overlooked STL algorithms: `nth_element` ([ref](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/nth_element.html)). It partially sorts the data in **O(N)** on average compared to O(N log (N)) for quicksort, such that a pivot (the nth element) is greater than all elements on one side and less than all elements on the other. The speedup versus quicksort can be quite significant with large inputs.

EDIT: if you want a certain range to be sorted, e.g. the 5 largest elements, you can use `partial_sort` ([ref](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/partial_sort.html)):

```
std::partial_sort(large_container.begin(), large_container.begin() + 5, large_container.end(), comparison_function);
```

Will partially sort large_container in *O(n + 5*log(5))*, such that the first five elements are the largest elements in large_container in descending order (or smallest elements in ascending order depending on the comparison function). This would probably replace a significant part of your code above.

Comment: Interesting function. But (and going solely by your description here), it would not guarantee the ordering of the top n elements, or does it? If it actually quicksorts till that point, the answer would be yes..

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, yes you assume correctly. `nth_element` uses the [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to partition the data into two partitions (greater and smaller than the nth element). `partial_sort` does the same, but follows up with heapsort on the first n elements.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I really should read up on these, they all sound very interesting. I think the code I posted below in my answer will be faster in practice; though if this is not a bottleneck the cleanliness of the `partial_sort` approach would certainly make it preferable.

Comment: Going very much off topic, but if you want to find bottle-necks you should also look into profilers (e.g. gprof for Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Start with the resulting deque that is initially empty and will be kept sorted for the duration of the algorithm:

1. Traverse elements.
2. For current element:

   - Insert it to the correct place in the resulting deque, so the ordering is preserved.
   - If the resulting deque contains more than 5 elements, remove the minimal element. Since deque is sorted, this is always the first element (or last, depending on sort "direction").

At the end, the resulting deque contains (up to) 5 largest elements. This is essentially O(n) algorithm.

Instead of the deque, you could use a vector with descending elements and remove from the end, or even a linked list (though pointer-chasing is never good for performance).

---

Alternatively, you could simply create additional map, that is "reverse" of your original map (i.e. what was value is now a key and vice-versa) and always add elements to both. This way, alternative map will always contain 5 largest elements near its end.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you sorting? You're making it way more complicated than it need to be.

Create a tree of 5 elements - this is your 5 largest elements. (Use an std::set)
Just loop over the contents, and each time you find a number bigger than the smallest number in the tree, add it into the tree and remove any overflow (numbers once in the top 5, no longer there)

Here's something I drew up in notepad in two minutes, no compilation guarantees:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int unordered[] = {7, 12, 11, 19, 88, 42, 3, 1, 22};

    set<int> biggest5;
    int smallest = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(unordered)/sizeof(int); ++i)
    {
        if (unordered[i] >= smallest)
        {
            biggest5.insert(unordered[i]);

            if(biggest5.size() > 5)
                biggest5.erase(biggest5.begin());

            smallest = *biggest5.begin();
        }
    }

    //All done
    cout << "Set: ";
    for (set<int>::reverse_iterator i = biggest5.rbegin(); i != biggest5.rend(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This should print

```
Set: 88 42 22 19 12
```

You could also trim the `biggest5` set after the traversal for maximum performance, at the cost of a bit more memory.

Answer (score 1):

std::sort is most likely to use QuickSort, or at least a variation over QuickSort called IntroSort, which "degenerates" to HeapSort when the recursion goes too deep. So both would run in O(nlogn) time. So it would not matter which one you select (if your own quicksort is implemented properly).

Answer (score 1):

I think a 5-element array may be small enough to be handled manually, by comparing the smallest element with each item in the map and adjust the array accordingly, so there's no need to call a sorting function. If a larger array is needed to be maintained, a heap may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution I thought of is using a priority_queue which makes sense considering what you are looking is elements with higher priority.

```
    #include <queue>

    int main(){
       priority_queue<int> q;
       int a[] = {7, 12, 11, 19, 88, 42, 3, 1, 22};
       for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++){
                q.push(a[i]);
       }
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         cout<<q.top()<<endl;
         q.pop();
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Note that the priority_queue internally is implemented as a heap and pop_heap operates in logarithmic time